# Kali linux crash on desktop

Tags: kali-linux, desktop, reboot, crash

I made a Kali bootable USB drive with latest Kali release (Kali linux 64 bit, version 2019.1a https://www.kali.org/downloads/). Loading Kali and doing any action on desktop (like moving mouse for a few seconds) make the system crash and reboot. This happens with any option in the boot menu except selecting Live (amd64 failsafe).

[image: boot menu]

I tried both simple bootable version and persistent storage one, in both cases I get the same issue. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: You should add the relevant logs and other important information to the question. If you don't know what the relevant logs are or how to find them, refer to the question linked in my previous comment.

Comment: See answer "If you need to ask, then Kali Linux is not the right distribution for you" in [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/399627#399627)

Comment: What kind of info do you need? How can I get them if each action I perform causes a crash of the system?

Comment: Did you checksum-verify the download of the LiveUSB image was correct? Please click on [edit] to reply which adds your response to the question; replying with another Comment as you just did means your response could scroll off the screen if more Comments are added.

Comment: Probably a hardware issue; what kind, who can say. You haven't given us any detail on the hardware platform. Have you tried this live OS USB device on other systems? Have other operating systems (live OR installed to the hardware) worked on this system? Troubleshooting 101.

Comment: @RoVo, a crash-and-reboot might be a kernel panic, which doesn't leave logs in any location the average user can access.